# Shuffle logs filling disk in EMR task nodes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have Spark 3 job running on EMR 6.9 and it is continuously running job. I am noticing gradual increase in disk usage of task nodes over time. I have noticed errors like this on the task nodes -

```
2023-04-12 22:02:45,532 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree (Container Monitor): Error reading the stream java.io.IOException: No such process
         at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
         at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
         at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
         at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
         at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
         at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree.constructProcessInfo(ProcfsBasedProcessTree.java:531)
         at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree.updateProcessTree(ProcfsBasedProcessTree.java:211)
         at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl$MonitoringThread.run(ContainersMonitorImpl.java:537)
```

It seems the tasks die and leave the shuffle logs but what could be  the cause for the tasks to die?
Restarting the job reduces the disk utilization.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java error it looks like Spark's temporary log file is growing very large and at a certain point in time forces the task to crash with an IO exception (happens when file size is [too large](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Map-and-Reduce-Error-Java-heap-space/td-p/45874) - that's the reason you see the disk usage shrinking on restart). You could:

- [lower logging level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html) to `WARN` or `ERROR` to reduce log file size
- set your memory allocation to a larger value, e.g. `-Xmx4096m`
- set a lifecycle for your tasks - e.g. restart tasks every few hours

Comment: Hello, the link you posted for mapreduce, the error in the question is for Spark. By memory allocation do you mean `spark.executor.memory` parameter?